# Stripe payment form to be embedded in iframe any security concerns?

Tags: security, iframe, payment

I've a project which connects different businesses who can sell their own products on my app and the payment gateway I used is Stripe. They connect their stripe account to my app through Stripe Connect and I charge on their behalf.

Now I would love to let the users to embed the paying form into their website as well through an iframe.
Are there any security issues that I should be aware of?

Note: I'm using the Stripe.js to process the payments so I don't need to worry about PCI Compliance

Thank you